# GParted vs Ubuntu Desktop/Server 20.04 own partition support

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, gparted

For Ubuntu `Desktop` and `Server` **20.04** - for creation and managing partitions - for installation purposes, is enough use the own `Ubuntu` support through the installer itself? or would be mandatory for some specific scenario use from the beginning use `GParted`? of course, prior to install Ubuntu.

Perhaps one option is better than the other for either old or new hardware support, same scenario as `MBR` vs `UIF`, and with/without dual-boot with Windows. I have old PC Desktop and new laptops too.

I want take/use the recommendable approach in general or for specific scenario(s) and do not do experiments with the hard-disk.

Comment: For most users, the default installer settings are chosen to be safe and sane. If you have unusual or complex needs, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1398950/edit) to specify. Generally, you can create partitions for those complex setups before, during, or after the install. Keep in mind that edits to *mounted* partitions are prohibited, so if you want to grow or shrink a partition containing, say, your root (`/`) filesystem, you can boot into a Live environment instead to do that.

Comment: It’s not unusual for new users to over complicate their partition scheme and then find they run out of space on one of the partitions. Unless you have good reasons that you understand it’s best to keep it simple and just use the defaults